# Storing type information only of a class in std::vector

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I would like to store an `std::string` and *something* in an `std::tuple` which is inside an `std::vector` for creating `std::unique_ptr`-s in runtime but not with an `if/else`. I would like something like this:

```
class A { };
class B : public A { static const std::string name() { return "B"; } };
class C : public A { static const std::string name() { return "C"; } };

class D 
{
public:
  D();
  void addItem(std:string name);
private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> my_items;
  std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, XXX something here XXX>> my_vector;
};

D::D() 
{
  my_vector.emplace_back(std::make_tuple(B::name(), YYY something here YYY));
  my_vector.emplace_back(std::make_tuple(C::name(), YYY something here YYY));
}

void D::addItem(std::string name)
{
  for (const auto &[typeName, YYY typeSomething YYY] : my_vector)
  {
    if (name == typeName)
    {
       my_items.emplace_back(std::make_unique<YYY typeSomething YYY>());
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried typeid and std::type_info, std::type_index but that is not for my case I think.

Comment: Factory pattern? Since the `YYY` is effectively a factory of `A`s. You could create static functions on `B` and `C` that create the new objects, and store function pointers inside `my_vector`; or for more flexibility you could store `std::function`s.

Comment: You can't store types - end of story. But you can store function pointers, maybe the std::make_unique<B> and std::make_unique<C> function pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably looking for `std::function`:

```cpp
class D 
{
public:
  D();
  void addItem(std:string name);
private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> my_items; 
  std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<A>()>>> my_vector;
};

D::D() 
{
  my_vector.emplace_back(std::make_tuple(B::name(), []{ return std::make_unique<B>(); }));
  my_vector.emplace_back(std::make_tuple(C::name(), []{ return std::make_unique<C>(); }));
}

void D::addItem(std::string name)
{
  for (const auto& [typeName, f] : my_vector)
  {
    if (name == typeName)
    {
       my_items.emplace_back(f());
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And then while you are at all, consider changing `my_vector` to be a `std::(unordered_)map` instead of a `std::vector`, and then `D::addItem()` can use `(unordered_)map::find()` more efficiently instead of using a manual loop.

Comment: Remy Lebeau thanks for the suggestion I will do that :)